# Cannot run program"python3":CreateProcesserror=2,The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install Spark and it seems the following mistake appears when i try to perform a simple calculation.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: Pyspark_err]

Answer (score 0):

run this in your terminal

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.9.7
```

see if it works now

Comment: After i run that on the terminal ,the response i get when i start pyspark is - " 'python3.9' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  Python version is 3.9.7

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30917473)

Comment: @ulubeyn: It looks like an answer to me. Why do you think it’s not an answer?

Comment: @Bobo_tren did you resolve this yet? I've come across this error in the past and it was related to my pyspark python version. Maybe try specifying 3.9.7 instead of 3.9. I've made an edit to my earlier answer.